# NodeJS: How can I update the view with multiple responses from subscribed websocket?

Tags: node.js, websocket, meanjs

I am new to websockets.

I am trying to implement a websocket in a MeanJS application to subscribe to some realtime data that another website provides, when data gets returned I'd like to update a table in my View with the results.

I've run into a logical issue. My implementation failed because it is trying to send multiple responses over a single tcp connection (I believe), it dies with the error:

```
throw new Error('Cant set headers after they are sent.');
```

I understand why this error is occuring, but being new to WebSockets and fairly new to NodeJS I'm not sure how to refactor this code in a manner that makes sense.

*In My Clientside Controller:*

```
    // Get Orderbook
    $scope.getOrderbook = function() {
        $http.get('exchanges/' + $stateParams.exchangeId + '/get_orderbook')
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log("ORDERBOOK DATA: " + data); // DEBUGGING
                $scope.orderBook = data;
            });
    };
```

*In My Server Side Controller:*

```
    exports.getOrderbook = function(req, res, next) {
        var exchange = req.exchange;

        if(exchange.slug === 'somesite') {
            var ws = new WebSocket('wss://www.somesite.com/realtimews');

            ws.on('open', function open() {
                ws.send('{"op": "subscribe", "args": "orderBook"}');
            });

            ws.on('message', function(message) {
                var response = JSON.parse(message);

                if(response.table) {
                    res.jsonp(response.data);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

**What's the best way to refactor this code so that I can subscribe to the websocket, receive messages from it, and when any message is received update the view with the data?**

Answer (score 0):

On each new incoming http request, you are trying to open a new websocket to some site and then each time you get a message you are trying to send a response.  Meanwhile, you never close your websocket.

The particular error you get happens when you try to send a second http response to the same http request when the first response has already been sent.  This will happen in your code when you get a second message on the websocket.

In addition, you open a new websocket everytime you get this request which just makes these open websockets accumulate.

If you really have to use a websocket to get your data, then you need to close the websocket as soon as you've gotten your first message or remove these event handlers that are associated with a particular request.

Here's one way to do it:

```
exports.getOrderbook = function(req, res, next) {
    var exchange = req.exchange;

    if(exchange.slug === 'somesite') {
        var ws = new WebSocket('wss://www.somesite.com/realtimews');

        ws.on('open', function open() {
            ws.send('{"op": "subscribe", "args": "orderBook"}');
        });

        ws.on('message', function(message) {
            var response = JSON.parse(message);

            if(response.table) {
                res.jsonp(response.data);
            } else {
                res.jsonp(/* some error response here */)
            }
            // close the websocket so we don't associate any more responses
            // with this particular http request
            ws.close();                
        });
    } else {
        // need to send some response here
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew why the error was occuring, I had missed the ws.close() though. 

If I were to implement it this way, with closing the websocket after a response is returned, I would have to continually send HTTP requests to call my server side function to get updates after the initial response.

This kind of defeats the purpose of subscribing to the websocket to get data back instead of performing long polling, which I was trying to avoid

Comment: @DaveRich - you can create a webSocket and store the socket reference globally if you want.  But in order to get that info back to the client you would need a persistent connection to the client (e.g. a websocket between client and server).  You did not really explain the overall context and architecture of the problem you're trying to solve so I'm not sure what to recommend.  Perhaps what you really should be doing is have each client connect itself with a websocket to the orderBook server directly so it can just get the realtime info from there?

Comment: @DaveRich - or, you can have one websocket connection to the realtime source from your server and have each client connect with a websocket to your server.  Then, anytime you receive realtime info on your server, you can immediately forward out appropriate data to any connected clients.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and implement this from the clientside controller and see how that works.